# Something went wrong. Heroku App Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, hosting

So Heroku has been down all day, of course I didn't realise this until I had made a tonne of changes to my app. Now Heroku is back up and my app is broken.

This is a block of random text to make stackoverflow think that I've explained my code block better, because they won't let me post otherwise.

This is my heroku log:

```
2012-06-30T22:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/application_helper.rb:23:in `landing_photo'
2012-06-30T22:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pages/home.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_pages_home_html_erb__3529485503375966156_14193960'
2012-06-30T22:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-30T22:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-30T22:58:31+00:00 heroku[router]: GET jasonmccarthy.ie/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=195ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-06-30T22:58:31+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 194.46.182.60 - - [30/Jun/2012:22:58:31 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 643 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11" jasonmccarthy.ie
2012-06-30T22:58:48+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Awaiting client
2012-06-30T22:58:48+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2012-06-30T22:58:48+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-06-30T22:58:54+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited with status 0
2012-06-30T22:58:54+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to complete
2012-06-30T22:58:57+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-30T22:58:57+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-30T22:58:57+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 194.46.182.60 at 2012-06-30 22:58:57 +0000
2012-06-30T22:58:57+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2012-06-30T22:58:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms)
2012-06-30T22:58:57+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
2012-06-30T22:58:57+00:00 heroku[router]: GET jasonmccarthy.ie/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=15ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-06-30T22:58:57+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-30T22:58:57+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert Range into Integer):
2012-06-30T22:58:57+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <% provide(:title, 'Jason Mc Carthy | Fashion Photography Wedding Photography') %>
2012-06-30T22:58:57+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: 
2012-06-30T22:58:57+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <%= landing_photo %>
2012-06-30T22:58:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/application_helper.rb:23:in `landing_photo'
2012-06-30T22:58:57+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: 
2012-06-30T22:58:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/application_helper.rb:23:in `rand'
2012-06-30T22:58:57+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: <span id="tagline">Endeavouring to build a creative &amp; inspiring 2D world</span>
2012-06-30T22:58:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pages/home.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_pages_home_html_erb__3529485503375966156_14193960'
2012-06-30T22:58:57+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-30T22:58:57+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-30T22:58:57+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 194.46.182.60 - - [30/Jun/2012:22:58:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 643 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11" jasonmccarthy.ie
2012-06-30T23:04:47+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-06-30T23:05:24+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v30 created by colmtuite@gmail.com
2012-06-30T23:05:24+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy b7f77bc by colmtuite@gmail.com
2012-06-30T23:05:24+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2012-06-30T23:05:25+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-06-30T23:05:26+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 18620`
2012-06-30T23:05:27+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-06-30T23:05:28+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-06-30 23:05:28] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2012-06-30T23:05:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2012-06-30T23:05:29+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-06-30T23:05:29+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-06-30T23:05:34+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-06-30 23:05:34] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2012-06-30T23:05:34+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-06-30 23:05:34] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2012-06-30T23:05:34+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-06-30 23:05:34] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=18620
2012-06-30T23:05:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.3 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:18620
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 194.46.182.60 at 2012-06-30 23:05:36 +0000
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (79.1ms)
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 108ms
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert Range into Integer):
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <% provide(:title, 'Jason Mc Carthy | Fashion Photography Wedding Photography') %>
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: 
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <%= l
anding_photo %>
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: 
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: <span id="tagline">Endeavouring to build a creative &amp; inspiring 2D world</span>
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/application_helper.rb:23:in `rand'
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/application_helper.rb:23:in `landing_photo'
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pages/home.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_pages_home_html_erb__3704543374435589796_23990640'
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 heroku[router]: GET jasonmccarthy.ie/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=238ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-06-30T23:05:36+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 194.46.182.60 - - [30/Jun/2012:23:05:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 643 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11" jasonmccarthy.ie
2012-06-30T23:05:37+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2012-06-30T23:05:37+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2012-06-30T23:05:38+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2012-06-30T23:05:49+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2012-06-30T23:05:51+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-30T23:05:51+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-30T23:05:51+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 194.46.182.60 at 2012-06-30 23:05:51 +0000
2012-06-30T23:05:51+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2012-06-30T23:05:51+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
2012-06-30T23:05:51+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
2012-06-30T23:05:51+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-30T23:05:51+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert Range into Integer):
2012-06-30T23:05:51+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: 
2012-06-30T23:05:51+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <% provide(:title, 'Jason Mc Carthy | Fashion Photography Wedding Photography') %>
2012-06-30T23:05:51+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <%= landing_photo %>
2012-06-30T23:05:51+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: 
2012-06-30T23:05:51+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: <span id="tagline">Endeavouring to build a creative &amp; inspiring 2D world</span>
2012-06-30T23:05:51+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/application_helper.rb:23:in `rand'
2012-06-30T23:05:51+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/application_helper.rb:23:in `landing_photo'
2012-06-30T23:05:51+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pages/home.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_pages_home_html_erb__3704543374435589796_23990640'
2012-06-30T23:05:51+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-30T23:05:51+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-30T23:05:51+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 194.46.182.60 - - [30/Jun/2012:23:05:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 643 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11" jasonmccarthy.ie
2012-06-30T23:05:51+00:00 heroku[router]: GET jasonmccarthy.ie/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=13ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-06-30T23:05:52+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 23782`
2012-06-30T23:05:52+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-06-30T23:05:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2012-06-30T23:05:53+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-06-30 23:05:53] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2012-06-30T23:05:57+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-06-30T23:05:57+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
```

Application Helper:

```
def landing_photo
   random = Random.rand(1..4)
   image_tag "home-#{random}.png", {:class => 'bg'}
end
```

Pages/home:

```
<%= landing_photo %>
```

Comment: The error seems to be some kind of conversion error in the `landing_photo` method, and from what I can tell from the logs, it looks like it's somehow related to a random randomizer om some sort. Try to see if you can reproduce it locally, or maybe put some of that code (the `landing_photo` method, for example) here.

Comment: @Frost Ok I added the randomizer code. It seems strange that this could cause a problem, this code hasn't been touched since before Heroku went down as far as I know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might be a Ruby version issue as `random = Random.rand(1..4)` works just fine on my system running MRI-1.9.3. Perhaps the electrical storm caused Heroku to change your Ruby. Maybe you were relying on the now defunct labs plugin for 1.9.3.

Check which version you're running under with `heroku run ruby -v`, and you can force them to use 1.9.3 by putting the following at the top of your gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
```

Comment: I think you're on to something here. I can't run bundle though when I add that ruby version to my Gemfile. It's returning an error.

Comment: ahh, I think you probably need to upgrade your bundler version to [1.2.0.pre](http://rubygems.org/gems/bundler/versions/1.2.0.pre) - just run `gem install bundler -v 1.2.0.pre --pre`

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong parameters for the rand method, it only accepts an integer, not a Range of them.

You are looking for

```
random = Random.rand(4)
```

Your other option is not using Random, but using an [Array#sample](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-sample)

```
random = (1..4).to_a.sample
```

Comment: .rand does accept a range in MRI-1.9.3, so if this code was working, then the Ruby Version the app runs under has probably changed somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you haven't pushed any new code to Heroku that introduced some buggy code.

I would check to see if you can reproduce the error locally.  If everything is solid, I would just try re-deploying your latest code to heroku again.

Comment: Everything is fine locally. I pushed some changes during the outage, updated rails versions etc. I've tried to revert to the way my code was before I changed anything. I pushed my latest code, still doesn't work.